# Error: NG0100 without any value change. Why would that message show up with a fix value?

Tags: angular

I have the below code sections that yields the famous NG100 error.

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
         [class.mat-row-compact]="false"></mat-row>
```

`false` should of course be a component member but replacing it with a fix expression should definitely eliminate the error. So I thought! Only when I use `undefined` instead of `false`the NG100 error disappears.

Could anyone give me a clue?

Comment: work fine for me, do you have a stackblitz?

Comment: I guess / hope, on the way to a stackblitz sample, the error will vanish and that would give me a clue.